# phpmyadmin graphics on user interface not working

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, freebsd

/phpmyadmin is not showing the phpmyadmin graphic and after I login as 'root' none of the buttons or graphics working, currently using the default theme, and I also installed a new theme and selected from the dropdown box.  The new theme loads but there is no graphics or icons on the UI.  However,... /setup is showing graphics fine.

FreeBSD 9.1-p6
I installed from ports phpMyAdmin-4.05
and Apache2

Answer (score 1):

You could try clearing your browser cache for that site and trying to load it again. Does your webserver error log have any hints? Does the webserver access log have references to any .png files?